# On what occasions should you use 'sh -c' instead of directly executing a program?

Tags: shell, command-line

I often see stuff like

```bash
sh -c "curl -o …"
```

Under what circumstances should you use that instead of just

```bash
curl -o …
```

Comment: In most cases you probably shouldn't but someone might use `sh -c` to force the use of posix shell where most people's login shell will either be bash or zsh.

Comment: While I've seen the use of `sh -c`, I've never seen something like **this**. Can you add a real-world example, so that we can explain better?

Comment: I saw a real life example where a file is curled to /usr/bin, I don‘t know why you should use this.

Comment: @Notiq please really paste / link to that example. we can't guess what you mean. And the way your question is currently stated the answer is "no, you should not prefer the first to the second".

Comment: In `systemd` services, the `ExecStart=` line does not run a shell.  It just runs the first token as a program, and passes the remaining tokens as arguments.  Things like `&&` aren't understood by `systemd` because it isn't a shell.  Therefore when we want to be fancy, we need to put these commands in a shell like  `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "curl -o ... 2>&1 >file && echo done`

Comment: How on earth is this a "request for learning materials"?

Comment: @PhilipCouling I want to understand how and why to use this.

Comment: @Notiq that's fine, it was just a weird close vote on this question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling Oh okay, thx for the information, just noticed how much more you get informed here than on SO, within 5 mins I got this massive answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you don't do this if you can avoid it.  Your two examples are basically identical.

However this is a relatively common pattern where you want to use shell operators inside the process.  For example where you use redirect operator `>` or pipe `|`.

These two are subtly different:

```bash
curl -o example.com/foo > foo
```

```bash
sh -c "curl -o example.com/foo > foo"
```

In the first, your current command line shell creates the file `foo` and attaches an open file handle onto the stdout of `curl`.  In the second, you create a new shell process and that new process is responsible for creating `foo` and attaching it to curl.

### Why might you need this?

#### Permissions

This becomes really important when the command you are running has different constraints to your current shell.  For example `sudo` runs a command as a different user to your current shell.  Therefore these two are **really** different:

```bash
sudo curl -o example.com/foo > foo
```

```bash
sudo sh -c "curl -o example.com/foo > foo"
```

In the first, the file `foo` is opened by your current shell and so is opened or created by your user.

In second the file is opened or created by the user `root` with unrestricted access.

#### Delayed Shell expansion

One other reason might be to delay variable expansion.  I don't have a useful example.  But in rare cases it can be useful to delay when / where a variable is expanded.

```bash
hello=wave
echo $hello
```

```bash
hello=wave
sh -c 'echo $hello'
```

These actually produce different results because the variable `hello` is not exported and therefore not available in the `sh` shell.

Comment: Nice example.  Though I'd argue that you could still avoid calling `sh` by doing `curl -o example.com/foo | sudo tee foo > /dev/null`

Comment: @Stewart yeah it's just a pattern. I most commonly see it for setting kernel params. `sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/...'`. Some use `tee` some use `sh -c` but it amounts to the same thing.